Historical manga in which the female lead has to change the fate of the villain

I don't know if it's a Chinese, Korean, or Japanese manga.

I remember that the female lead gets reincarnated into an ancient manga where she has to change the villain's fate.

She found him (the villain) maybe in a cave before him evolving into villain form, abandoned by the original female lead and male lead. He was badly hurt and she saved him.

I think our female lead also told him and she came to help him.

After that, they both come out of the cave and are going through the market. There, they meet the original female lead and male lead. They were mocking our male lead (the villain), then our female lead stood up for him.



Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

I am afraid I don't remember female lead hair colour and I think maybe I read it in kiss manga or zin manga site.guys please help me I really want to read that manga but I couldn't remember what's that manga name

It's been very long time since I read that manga maybe 5 6 years ago

likely this is manhua. And this is one of those "fast isekai" (CN term about multiple story where FML would get isekai into a "cannon fodder" then save suppose to be villain MC of that world and go on),  because I don't recall any manhwa and manga with these kind of story telling.

I try to find that manhua so hard but no luck
